# Is there any way to change data type of each item of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, types

I have a listof lists named `listlog` with this structure:

```
[['2022-05-04 11:06:50', 'INFO', 'Database Connection', 'Database', '10.05', 'NULL'] [...]
```

Is there any way to change each item data type? The first one would be timestamp/datetime, the scond, third and fourth would be string, the fith would be float or numeric.

Is there any way?
I've tested something like this, but didn't work

```
map(lambda item: Timestamp([item[0]]), listLog)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
from datetime import datetime
for item in listdata:
        item[0]=datetime.strptime(item[0], '%Y-%M-%d %H:%m:%S')
        item[1]=str(item[1])
        item[2]=str(item[2])
        item[3]=str(item[3])
        item[4]=float(item[4])

print(listt)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it with something like the following:

```
for item in listlog:
    item[0] = Timestamp(item[0])
    item[4] = float(item[4])
```

Add an additional assignment for each data field that you need to convert.

Comment: thanks, it worked. I don't need the first line though. the table automatically accepts the value as datetime type. other than that, it worked for what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While I think Greg Hewgill's solution is the best practice, here is an answer using a map if you're interested in oneliners:

```
 list(map(lambda item: [Timestamp(item[0])] + item[1:4] + [float(item[4])] + item[5:], listlog))
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
for i in range(0,len(list_name)):
     # check condition of the item whether its a string or integer or date-time stamp then do typecasting.
```

for example : `if type(l[item])=int` and you want to convert it to string then write:

```
l[item] = string(l[item])
```